Fear shirk to shaking hand with a hindu in a condition
Assalamu alaikum brother.If I shake hand with a hindu in such a time when I can understand his amulet may be touched with my hand, will it considered as shirk? I will not make him crony.

I can't speak for the Islamic view, but from sheer logic: 1., you do not intend to touch it, 2. you do not believe it to be associated to Allah, nor a substitute or anything like that. Another thought: cats were sacred in pre-Islamic Egypt. Still you don't run away or try to kill them.

@UmH from your link: "Or, if it is done by believing someone/something can do things which only Allah is able to do, but by mouth he says that there is no ilah (god) other than Allah, then this kind of shirk is called 'Concealed Shirk' or 'Lesser Shirk'." Does that imply that believing the amulet in question, itself, is shirk is already shirk? The way that not only the Hindu in question might partner the Amulet to the Almighty but for the questioner to fear that this might be true?

No it is not shirk. Shirk is associating other partners with Allah. You didn't mean to touch it and you know you touching it does nothing.
